# Assassination-Classroom Ost ep19 season 2

Tags: music, assassination-classroom

In the episode 41 of assassination classroom (season 2 episode 19) at 4:05 of the episode there a music played, if anyone know the name of the song ?

Answer (score 1):

Assassination Classroom 2nd Season Ost - 02. 解き明かされる謎 [Tokiakasa Reru Nazo]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHYF3Dsg2ck